# Proving H intersect K is subspace of H

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $H$ and $ K$ are subspaces of vector space $V$.
How to prove $H\cap K$ is subspace of $H$?

Comment: (a) check it's closed under addition & scalar multiplication, (b) check that it's a subset.

Comment: While you're at it, its could be instructive to think about why the union of two subspaces is not a subspace. This is something of a theme with "subobjects" as you'll see

Answer (score 1):

To show that something is a subspace you have to show three things:

1. It's closed under scalar multiplication.
2. It's closed under addition
3. It's non-empty

I'll do (1) so that you can see how it goes, you'll have to do (2) and for (3) show that it contains $0$.

To show that $H \cap K$ is closed under scalar multiplication assume $v \in H \cap K$ is a vector and $r$ is a scalar.  I need to show that $rv$ is contained in $H \cap K$.

As $v \in H \cap K$ and $H \cap K$ is exactly the set of vectors contained in both $H$ and $K$ we know that $v$ is contained in both $H$ and $K$.  We are told that $H$ is a subspace and subspaces are closed under scalar multiplication so $v \in H$ implies $rv \in H$.  With the same kind of argument you can get $rv \in K$ as well.  Now $rv$ is contained in both $H$ and $K$ so by definition $rv \in H \cap K$.  This proves that $H \cap K$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Treat them as groups, and show that they intersection must be closed under addition, inverses. Then show that this subgroup is closed under linear combination.

Comment: Can you go in detail and show it?

Comment: What's the fun in that? It's easier than it sounds once it occurs to you, and doing it on your own will make you more confident that you can interact with mathematics, not just read theorems and accept there's some way to prove them.